# Find particular Checkbox from CheckBoxList via JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have some trouble finding a particular Checkbox.
In a dynamic asp.net CheckboxList with approximately 100 Checkboxes, I have a right click context menu and want to get the particular Checkbox on which I opened the context menu.

```
<%= checkboxlist.ClientID%>
```

only gets me the whole checkboxlist

---

Here is my javascript/JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowMenu(control, e) {
        var posx = e.clientX + window.pageXOffset + 'px';
        var posy = e.clientY + window.pageYOffset - 10 + 'px';
        document.getElementById(control).style.position = 'absolute';
        document.getElementById(control).style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById(control).style.left = posx;
        document.getElementById(control).style.top = posy;
        var parent = document.getElementById('<%= cbl_Machines.ClientID%>');
    };

    function HideMenu(control) {
        document.getElementById(control).style.display = 'none';
    };

    $(document).on('click', '#divSelectAll', function () {
        $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
        __doPostBack();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#divDeselectAll', function () {
        $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
        __doPostBack();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#divAddMachine', function () {
        window.location.replace("../MemberPages/CreateMachine.aspx");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#divModifyMachine', function () {
        alert('<%=cbl_Machines.ClientID%>');
    });
</script>
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="leftBox" onmousedown="HideMenu('contextMenu');"oncontextmenu="ShowMenu('contextMenu',event);">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbl_Machines" Width="100%" RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="cblmachines" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbl_Machines_SelectedIndexChanged" />
    <div style="padding: 0px 5px; border: 1px solid black; border-top-style: none">
        <asp:Button ID="btn_CreateMachine" Width="33%" runat="server" Text="Add Machine" OnClick="btn_CreateMachine_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_ModifyMachine" Width="32%" runat="server" Text="Modify Machine" OnClick="btn_ModifyMachine_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_DeleteMachine" Width="32%" runat="server" Text="Delete Machine" OnClick="btn_DeleteMachine_Click" />
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="contextMenu" onmouseup="HideMenu('contextMenu');">
    <table border="0" style="border: thin solid #808080; cursor: default; width: 150px; background-color: white">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="divSelectAll" class="ContextItem">Select All</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="divDeselectAll" class="ContextItem">Deselect All</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="divAddMachine" class="ContextItem">Add Machine</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="divModifyMachine" class="ContextItem">Modify Machine</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

And last but not least my Code Behind

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Configuration.DeserializeFromXMLMachines();

            var orderedList = Configuration.ManagedMachines.OrderBy(x => x.MachineName);
            foreach (var item in orderedList)
            {
                cbl_Machines.Items.Add(item.MachineName+ "<a class='HLdetails' href=\"MachineDetails.aspx?Name=" + item.MachineName + "\">></a>");
            }
        }
```

When I right click in the 'leftBox' Div the following Context Menu appears

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvlho.jpg

And now when I click on Modify Machine I only need the value of this checkbox where the Context Menu opens. In this Case the one with the value Test24.

Comment: Where is the code for your menu event? You can't use server code to isolate a UI event

Comment: Samy - I edited in the additional data from the "answer" you posted. Please [edit] this question to ensure it reads as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `checkboxlist.SelectedItem` and its' attributes could get you somewhere. You would have to set a Value or a unique HTML id to each individual checkbox to allow jQuery to actually find it.

You could also go from where you already are by searching within the `input` children (the checkboxes) of the CheckBoxList of which you already have the ClientID. Supposing only one checkbox is selected, this code will return its' associated jQuery object (untested, dev tools not available to me right now):

```
var selected = $("#<%=checkboxlist.ClientID %> input:checked");
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I dont need the checked checkboxlist. I m trying to get only one checkbox where I right-clicked on. Any suggestions?

Comment: ok I found the clicked checkbox value via event.target.innerHTML

Comment: Whoops sorry, I misunderstood your question completely!